# Dual boot on a Samsung SSD EVO 860 whose factory files are removed

Tags: 20.04, ssd, windows-10, samsung

## Question

Factory files on a brand-new Samsung SSD 860 evo 500G are removed. Is it safe to install Windows and Ubuntu on it?

## Description

I have bought a brand-new Samsung SSD 860 evo 500GB. First, its volume was around 475GB. During the installation of a fresh ubuntu 20 on it, I had to click on `New Partition Table...`; this created 500.1GB of free space on the disk. I don't know what `factory files` have been there on the brand-new SSD before. I also don't know is it safe to install OS on it when these files are removed.

Comment: I do not think there were factory files.It may have just been formatted. Is your system UEFI or BIOS? You need to first create drive as gpt if using UEFI, most tools default to old MBR. Windows only installs in UEFI mode to gpt drives and UEFI highly suggests gpt. Be sure to install both systems in same boot mode, both UEFI or both old BIOS.

Comment: Why do you think there were "factory files" and what do you think they were?

Comment: @Sebastian Free space was around 475GB before I create partition table. After that, it was 500.1GB.

Comment: That's probably just a matter of different display conventions by different tools. Virtually every tool shows a different size for the same partition. Factory-new disks usually do not come with files on them.

Answer (score 0):

Wiping your SSD and installing a new partition table is completely safe and does not erase anything that can't allow Ubuntu and Windows to boot.

However you must install Windows 10 first, then make your Windows partition smaller and then install Ubuntu alongside it else Ubuntu will only allow you to erase the Windows partition or you will try to resize it in Ubuntu and the bootloader gets corrupted.